# Using RegEx to Validate User Input

Tags: regex, string, vb.net, validation, textbox

**RESOLUTION** - Provided By Wiktor - I have implemented this into my question.

Validating user input while they're typing to match the following format - 11A11

```
    Private Sub RegexFormatterExample(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim txt As TextBox = sender
    Dim pattern As String = ""

    Select Case txt.Name
        Case "txt_example"
            pattern = "^\d{1,2}(?:(?<=^\d{2})[A-Z]\d{0,2})?$"
        Case Else
            pattern = "^\d{1,2}(?:(?<=^\d{2})[A-Z]\d{0,2})?$"
    End Select

    Dim strText As String = txt.Text

    While Not Regex.IsMatch(strText, pattern) AndAlso Not strText = ""
        strText = strText.Substring(0, strText.Length - 1)
    End While

    txt.Text = strText
    txt.Select(txt.Text.Length, 0)
End Sub
```

I have also attached a .TextChanged handler to the specified txtbox.

The provided answer only allows the user to type in the following format which is what I asked for.

[image: What I want]

Thanks Wiktor!

**Edit**

Further to this scenario there is a case where the user has the ability to enter only a minus symbol rather than passing an empty string for where they don't know the value.

To implement this I amended the RegEx pattern to the following. [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hU9hI6/166)

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way but it seems to be working for me.

Comment: Like `^[A-Z]{2}[0-9][A-Z]{2}\z` ? See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%5b0-9%5d%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%5cz&i=AA1AA)

Comment: What is your Problem? Where is the fail. Provide more information.

Comment: btw: you dont need the {1} quantifier. [0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}\z. == [0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{2}\z

Comment: Try `^\d{1,2}(?:(?<=^\d{2})[A-Z]\d{0,2})?$`. [See the regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5bA-Z%5d%5cd%7b0%2c2%7d%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=24A33%0d%0a2222%0d%0a11A11%0d%0a2A22&o=m)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d{1,2}(?:(?<=^\d{2})[A-Z]\d{0,2})?\z
```

See the [.NET regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%7b1%2c2%7d%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5bA-Z%5d%5cd%7b0%2c2%7d%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=24A33%0d%0a2222%0d%0a11A11%0d%0a2A22&o=m) (`\z` is replaced with `\r?$` since the demo is run against a single multiline string).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?<=^\d{2})` - a positive lookbehind check: there must be two digits at the start of the string immediately to the left of the current position
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
  - `\d{0,2}` - 0, 1 or 2 digits
- `)?` - end of the non-capturing group, repeat 1 or 0 times (i.e. make it optional)
- `(?:[A-Z]\d{0,2})?` - an optional sequence of an uppercase letter and then 0, 1 or 2 digits
- `\z` - the very end of string (no `\n` is allowed at the end of the string).

Comment: I have implemented this into my question, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can trim \n off (if any) and use

```
"^[0-9]{2}[A-Z][0-9]{2}$"
```

instead?